# Grant privileges on Roles but user cannot be granted

Tags: oracle

I have grant Roles for users and grant some privs on Roles:

```
--Grant roles for users
GRANT DataEntry TO John, Joe, Lynn;
GRANT Supervisor TO Fred;
GRANT Management TO Amy, Beth;

--Grant on table to roles
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON Attendance TO DataEntry;
GRANT SELECT, DELETE ON Attendance TO Supervisor;
GRANT SELECT ON Attendance TO Management;
```

However, when I query to dba_sys_privs table and select on John user, for example, I do not have privs which DataEntry role have? What happened with that problem?

Comment: It only have roles, no user found!

Answer (score 2):

John has been granted the role, not the privileges of the role directly. John will be able to take advantage of those privileges through the role. This means that if you were to `revoke` the role from the user, Oracle wouldn't need to go back and figure out which privileges were obtained through the role and revoke those too - this would be a challenge as a user might be granted multiple roles that provide the say privilege. It is much more efficient for Oracle to check if a user has access to a necessary privilege at parse time (which doesn't happen often).

If you want to see all the table privileges a user is able to use then you would need to look at both `dba_tab_privs` and `dba_role_privs`. Remember that a role can be granted another role so you would need to do a recursive query to identify all of those too:

```
with grantees (schema) as
 (Select username schema
  from   dba_users
  where  username = 'JOHN'
union all
  select rp.granted_role
  from   grantees g
  join   dba_role_privs rp
    on   g.schema = rp.grantee
 )
select  *
from    dba_tab_privs sp
where   sp.grantee in (select g.schema from grantees g)
```

Comment: So I don't know how to select the ```Attendance``` table by John.  When I log in to John and I select to that table, it throws an error ```table or view does not exists```

Comment: `attendance` on it's own for the user John will reference the `attendance` table or view in the John schema. You need to tell Oracle which schema's `attendance` table you want to use: `select blah from my_other_user.attendance`. You can also create a synonym to achieve the same without specifying the schema.